# how to properly use exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help advice. I can not determine what the code more correct.

UserController variant1:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)   

  if  @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome  to  the Sample  App!"
    redirect_to  @user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid data' 
    render  'new'
  end
end
```

UserController variant2:

```
def create
  begin
    @user = User.new(user_params)   
    @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome  to  the Sample  App!"
    redirect_to  @user
  rescue      
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid data' 
    render  'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variant 1 is more correct for a couple of reasons. Here's some broad points. Exceptions should be exceptional. They should be caught AND raised. When you are raising exceptions you should be looking for specific exceptions as well. I know these are broad points but you should read up on exceptions- here's the Rails guide on using exceptions in controllers http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html.